# Youre a big drinker right? Can you interpret for the drunk?

Tags: wordplay, word-problem, language

Be gentle!  I'm trying something new...  I'd like a full translation/interpretation, and bonus points if you spot the pattern. I expect it'll be easy as pie so think of it as a race.

A VERY drunken, foreign, genius chemistry professor needs help locating something (we think) but between his broken English and drunken rambling no one can understand a word he's saying.  Can you?

Here's what he's been saying:

> *burp* hare *hic* sit *burp* on?
>
> ha *hic* vie loss *hic* tit?
>
> tomb *hic* any ban *hic* gone my head!
>
> ewer hell *hic* ping?
>
> goo *hic* die knee *hic* ding it!
>
> well like *hic* aunt fine *hic* dad *hic* rum aye had.
>
> it *hic* snot in *burp* reusable plaice.
>
> it was knot four may *hic* king mew *hic* sick.
>
> oar fall *hic* *burp* incensing two it.
>
> it *hic* snot force *hic* topping *burp* auto-beagles.
>
> its hole *hic* dings *hic* tough butt eye dome *hic* *burp* trinket.
>
> it *burp* dose knot flow *hic* tanned aye thing *hic* kit no *hic* sow to sew *hic* barmy up.
>
> aye kneed *burp* accrue *hic* are!
>
> the cue  *hic* *burp* risk *burp* shone add *hic* rum!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Pretty sure I missed most of these, but it was fun to try.**

burp hare hic sit burp on?

> 1. Where's it gone?

ha hic vie loss hic tit?

> 2. Have I lost it?

tomb hic any ban hic gone my head!

> 3. Too many bang on my head!

ewer hell hic ping?

> 4. Were you helping?

goo hic die knee hic ding it!

> 5. Good, I needing it!

well like hic aunt fine hic dad hic rum aye had.

> 6. Well, I can't find that drum I had.

it hic snot in burp reusable plaice.

> 7. It's not in the usual place.

it was knot four may hic king mew hic sick.

> 8. It was not for making music.

oar fall hic burp incensing two it.

> 9. Or for listening to it.

it hic snot force hic topping burp auto-beagles.

> 10. It's not for stopping automobiles. (credit [BunjiquoBianco](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22222/bunjiquobianco))

its hole hic dings hic tough butt eye dome hic burp trinket.

> 11. It's holding stuff, but I don't drink it.

it burp dose knot flow hic tanned aye thing hic kit no hic sow to sew hic barmy up.

> 12. It does not float and I think it knows how to sober me up. (credit [kayzeroshort](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25056/kayzeroshort))

aye kneed burp accrue hic are!

> 13. I need a cure here! (credit [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan))

the cue hic burp risk burp shone add hic rum!

> 14. The cure is on a drum. (credit [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan))

Comment: That got me grinning.  You've got about 60% correct.  +1

Comment: Lines 2,3,5,7 and 9 are fine...

Comment: I think 12.5 is "it knows how to sober me up"

Comment: @kayzeroshort well done +1

Comment: line 6: "drum"
line 8: "music"

Comment: I think the last two lines may be "I need a cure", "the cure is on a drum". I guess there's a reference here to something (drum-shaped, called "Drum", I dunno) that I'm not familiar with and that is meant to be some kind of cure for drunkenness.

Comment: @Garethmccaughan Sharp as usual.  +1

Comment: it hic snot force hic topping burp auto-beagles => It's not for stopping automobiles  -- drum brakes, so fit's in with the drum theme

Comment: 4: You were helping?

Comment: @michaSprengers yeah, it should be "You're helping?" +1